# Log output to syslog

Tags: drush

I run various Drush commands, including lots of queues, in a loop. I want to see the output in my syslog.

I am currently using `drush -r /var/www queue-run my_queue_name_here 2>&1 | logger`, which outputs the following line.

> Processed 2 items from the my_queue_name_here queue in 0.58

This is OK, but I feel like this must be wrong. Surely many people want to direct Drush messages to the syslog. Is it possible without using the logger as above?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible natively. You could write a Drush commandfile, and call `drush_set_context('DRUSH_LOG_CALLBACK', 'my_log_function');` to intercept log messages. See [drush_log()](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.0.0-rc3/includes/drush.inc#L1248) for details.

A pull request could be considered; it would need to fail gracefully if someone attempted to use it on a system that did not have syslog. Drush avoids platform-specific features where possible, though, which is probably why this has not been added as a standard feature to date.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a possible solution from [askubuntu.com - How do I log all input and output in a terminal session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session)

```
$script $HOME/yourlogfile.log
$drush {your command}
$exit
$cat $HOME/yourlogfile.log
```

Hope this works out for you. :)